# Error with NaN using sklearn in python

Tags: python

My Code:

```
### Working with NaN using sklearn
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
### Mean strategy
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=1) 
imp.fit([1,5,9,np.NaN])
X = [1,5,9,np.NaN]
y = imp.transform(X)
print (y)
```

After running I am getting below warning message:
C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. DeprecationWarning)

How to solve it? I tried the reshape but it is giving error message saying: 
'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Please help.

Comment: you should create an array here `imp.fit([1,5,9,np.NaN])` change to `imp.fit(np.array([1,5,9,np.NaN]))` and `X = [1,5,9,np.NaN]` should be `X = np.array([1,5,9,np.NaN])` not sure if you still need to reshape but the type at least will be compatible with sklearn

Comment: Stii getting below error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b707e4784d60> in <module>()
      3 from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
      4 imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=1) ### Mean strategy
----> 5 imp.fit(np.array[1,5,9,np.NaN])
      6 #X.reshape(-1, 1)
      7 X =np.array([1,5,9,np.NaN])

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

so i ran your code and changed `X` do a 2d list... Turns out that because you were passing a 1D array to transform so it was throwing you the error... So i made it a 2D lisst

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
### Mean strategy
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=1)
imp.fit([1,5,9,np.NaN])
X = [[1,5,9,np.NaN]]           # < =========== The change that I made 
y = imp.transform(X)
print(y)
enter code here
```